# Edit an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

table1 has the columns:

```
id name  value event
1  name1  0.5   f
2  name2  1.9   f
3  name3  2.6   f
4  name4  0.2   f
5  name5  0     r
6  name6  text  r
7  name7  text2 t
8  name8  5     t
....
999  name999 4.7  f
```

table2 has the columns

```
id risk     value
1  very low 0
1  low      0.5
2  medium   1.5
3  high     2.5
4 very high 3
```

result:

```
1  name5    very high
2  name6    very high
3  name999  high
4  name3    high
5  name2    medium
6  name1    low
7  name7    very low
8  name8    very low
```

the query so far is (without the event of r and t to give very high and very low is):

```
    SELECT table1.id
     , table1.event
     , table2.risk 
    FROM table1
     JOIN table2
      ON table2.value = ( SELECT MAX(table2.value)
                   FROM table2
                   WHERE table2.value <= table1.value
                 )
    ORDER BY table1.value DESC
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It is not clear from your example.

Comment: Why are there text values in what appears to be a decimal 'value' column in table1? If they are there, how should they be handled? Could you also write how you want your results table to be calculated? It's not clear why 'name5' should be paired with 'very high' and id 1 for example.

Comment: this is bad as it is... IDK what good this whole thing would do, but I'd suggest starting over and rethinking if you want a decent database to back it.

Comment: @howard. I want to achieve if the event is "f" then from table2 to get the risk. Else If the event is "r" to get very high (value doesnt matter).Else If the event is "t" to get very low (value doesnt matter too)

Comment: @Gus In table2 very low and very high are appearing only to help with the sorting of the result (DESC). Because "value" column is getting its values from a textbox (it's default value is text). Name5 should be pairing with very high because his event in table1 is "r"

Comment: @Gabor Magyar . That's the drowback when you messing android with mysql.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,
   CASE table1.event
     WHEN 'r' THEN 'very high'
     WHEN 't' THEN 'very low'
     ELSE (SELECT table2.risk FROM table2 WHERE table2.value <= table1.value
           ORDER BY table2.value DESC LIMIT 1)
   END AS risk
FROM table1
ORDER BY FIELD( table1.event, 'r', 'f', 't' ), table1.value DESC
```

Comment: In "r" event is correct (very high) but I need for "t" event to be "very low" instead of "very high".

Comment: @aniso Edited to add 't' event condition.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'medical.event = 'r' THEN 'very high' ELSEIF medical.event = 't' at line 2

Comment: @aniso Oh! sorry about that I often mix different languages! corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works in SQL Server 2008 and should be pretty close to what you need in mySQL

```
select t1.*,coalesce(a.risk,b.risk,c.risk) as risk
from t1 
left join 
( select risk from t2 where id = (SELECT MAX(t2.value) 
      FROM t2,t1 WHERE t2.value <= t1.value))
 a on t1.event='f' 
left join t2 b on t1.event='r' and b.id=5
left join t2 c on t1.event='t' and c.id=1
order by t1.value desc
```

Comment: for event "f" all I get are NULL's everywhere

Comment: I suspect mySQL isn't handling the comparison of value properly.   Try running the inner query by itself and see what comes back...